# /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ContentVersion rest api Limitation

Tags: rest-api, api, limits, contentversion

I'm using the standard rest API that salesforce suggest for upload files : 
/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ContentVersion - and converting the file to base64 blob on the VersionData param.

I want to know simply : 
What is the max size in MB that I can upload with this method?

**I saw in one place that the limitation is standing on 50 MB :** 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm
- Please see : "VersionData".

**And on the other hand 2GB  :** 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

Can someone please help?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is explicitly stated at the top of the document from the second link:

> You can insert or update blob data using a non-multipart message, but you are limited to 50 MB of text data or 37.5 MB of base64–encoded data.

In other words, both values that are quoted are correct; it depends on which API and method you use to upload the file.

Comment: I'm still trying to get it - using multipart message with the standard salesforce API  : /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ContentVersion - Should I need to something more than just add multipart/form-data to the Header under Content Type?
Thanks, and sorry if it silly question - just trying to understand @sfdcfox

Comment: @ItaiR it should be `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="boundary_string"` The semi-colon and boundary attribute are important here.

Comment: Thanks!!
:)
@sfdcfox